# How do I call a fromRootViewController method within a UIView class?

Tags: swift, admob

EDIT: This is a very beginner level question, so I apologise in advance

This is a sub part of a homework assignment I'm trying to crack but seems kind of impossible. I have implemented GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate to my UIView for Rewarded ads on Google Admob, and managed to implement all other instances of this delegate within "PopUp", which is a subclass of UIView.

However, this one method seems impossible to implement, which is:

```
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {    
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
         }
```

where the issue is the ".present(fromRootViewController: self) portion of the code since the self refers not to a ViewController but to a UIView().

I honestly don't know how to tackle this situation, so I do not have anything to show for my attempts at this issue. I would really be grateful for any guidance that I can get on this topic, I've been stuck here for the better part of 2 days.

Here is the popUp class in case it helps make my code clearer

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class Popup: UIView, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
        let vc = MainVC()
        vc.lifeNumber += 3
        vc.numberOfLivesLabel.text = "\(vc.lifeNumber)"
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
    }


    let playButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func play() {
        print("Play button pressed.")
        if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {
            GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self) //<---------ERRONEOUS CODE
             }
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self


self.addSubview(popUpContainer)
playButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpContainer.centerXAnchor),
    playButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpContainer.topAnchor, constant: 15),
    playButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
    playButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Could not run init(coder)")
    }
}
```

And here is my MainVC()

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

    var lifeNumber: Int = 3

    lazy var numberOfLivesLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "\(lifeNumber)"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 25)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let buttonOne: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Hit me!", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        let popUpView = Popup()
        self.view.addSubview(popUpView)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        view.addSubview(buttonOne)
        view.addSubview(numberOfLivesLabel)

        buttonOne.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonOne.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        buttonOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

        numberOfLivesLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        numberOfLivesLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonOne.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: This Popup view _is_ managed by a VC, right? Can you show the code that makes use of `Popup`?

Comment: @Sweeper thank you for replying; I have added it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This code from hacking with swift will help.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-the-view-controller-responsible-for-a-view)

```
    extension UIView {
    func findViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
            return nextResponder
        } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
            return nextResponder.findViewController()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Use the extension to get the popups parent view controller.

```
if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {    
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self.findViewController())
     }
```

You might want to put it on the main queue as well

```
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {    
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self.findViewController())
     }
    }
```